# Transform a 1 by 1 matrix intro a variable or scalar

Tags: stata

How do transform a 1 by 1 matrix intro a variable or scalar? At the moment I have two matrices which are both 1 by 1, so in principle they are scalars. I would like to divide one of the values (which is the 1 by 1 matrix) by the other value (which is the other 1 by 1 matrix). 
I've read that one can do something like that

```
    C[`i',`j']= A[`i',`j']/B[`i',`j']
```

to do element by element operations in Stata. In this example one would loop over i and j. Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: "...did not work" is usually not enough information for people to resolve your exact issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Stata, variables and scalars are two different things. Variables are set up as columns in a Stata database; almost always the subject of some statistical analysis. A scalar is a storage type that holds some expression, be it numeric or string.

The code you show appears to be from this page: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/element-by-element-operations-on-matrices/, but you only post one part. That part makes use of **local macros**, but nowhere do you seem to define them. Furthermore, if you have a matrix with only one element, then you need not loop over the indices of the matrix. Its only element is held in position [1,1].

Below is an example of two matrices with one element each, whose division is saved in a scalar.

```
clear all
set more off

matrix A = (1)
matrix B = (2)

scalar c = A[1,1]/B[1,1]

display "scalar c is: " c
```

Stata has its own matrix language, Mata, in case you need "advanced" matrix features.

See at least `help macro`, `help scalar`, `help matrix`, `help forvalues` and `help mata`.